# If $\emptyset\subsetneq A\subseteq (0,1)$ and $a,b\in A, a<b\implies a/b\in A$ then $\sup A=1$or $\sup A\in A$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am looking for a simple and short solution of this problem using only basic definitions of $\sup$ etc. Here is my somewhat complicated solution that uses sequences and the Axiom of Countable Choice.

Obviously $0<\sup A\le 1$. Assume $\sup A\notin A$. Then there exists a sequence $x_n\in A$ that is strictly increasing and $x_n\to \sup A$. Indeed, take $x_1\in A$ so that
$$\sup A-1<x_1<\sup A$$
and having defined $x_1<...<x_n$, $x_i\in A$ so that
$$\sup A-\frac1n<x_n<\sup A$$
pick $x'_{n+1}\in A$ s.t.
$$\sup A-\frac1{n+1}<x'_{n+1}<\sup A$$
and $x_{n+1}\in A$ s.t.
$$\sup A-(\sup A-x'_{n+1})<x_{n+1}<\sup A\implies \sup A-\frac1{n+1}<x'_{n+1}<x_{n+1}<\sup A$$
By hypothesis,
$$x_n<x_{n+1}\implies \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\in A\implies \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\le \sup A\implies 1=\frac {\sup A}{\sup A}\le \sup A\le 1$$
hence $\sup A=1$

Comment: $\forall a\in (0,1), a\lt1\implies a\in A,$ so $A=(0,1)?$ Or $b$ cannot be $1?$

Comment: @awllower $a,b\in A$

Comment: @Optional That condition is not mentioned in the problem statement

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I know it's correct. I am looking for something simpler...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, I missed that. If $a,b$ were allowed to range $(0,+\infty)$ it would have been an incorrect problem.

Comment: In fact your proof is simple but the wording is a bit heavy.@Optional

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane This problem appears in a book just before the introduction of limits of sequences; it "should" be solvable with other tools as well